# how to insert value in textbox using combobox

Tags: vb.net

i would like to ask some help regarding combobox and textbox. so here's the problem, i've been trying to figure out how to assign a value into the textbox using the combobox and here's what it looks like

```
If yearlevel.SelectedItem = "Nursery" Then
    txtamount.Text = "1000"
    If yearlevel.SelectedItem = "Kinder" Then
        txtamount.Text = "2000"
    End If
End If
```

what i want to happen is that when i choose "Nursery" "1000" would automatically appear in the textbox.

Comment: How are you binding to the combobox? What is the data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
Private Sub yearLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yearLevel.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case yearLevel.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "Nursery" : txtAmount.Text = "1000"
        Case "Kinder" : txtAmount.Text = "2000"
    End Select
End Sub
```

To make it more dynamic and easy, when you add the items to the combobox, add it as an object containing both text and amount, then when selectedindexchanged occur, just cast the selectedobject back to your own object and use the amount value:

```
   Private Structure YearLevelItemStruct
    Private _Text As String
    Private _Amount As Double
    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Text
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Amount() As Double
        Get
            Return Me._Amount
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Amount As Double)
        Me._Text = Text
        Me._Amount = Amount
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _Text
    End Function
End Structure


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    loaditems()
End Sub
Sub loaditems()
    yearLevel.Items.Clear()
       yearLevel.Items.Add(New YearLevelItemStruct("Nursery", 1000))
    yearLevel.Items.Add(New YearLevelItemStruct("Kinder", 2000))
End Sub

Private Sub yearLevel_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles yearLevel.SelectedIndexChanged
    txtAmount.Text = DirectCast(yearLevel.SelectedItem, YearLevelItemStruct).Amount.ToString
End Sub
```

Of course, if you allready have all items in some list or array of some kind of object that has ToString() you'll not need to create an own structure to hold the object.
If your object does not have the ToString(), then you can use the combobox:s .DisplayMember="some_property_that_returns_a_string". Because if it does not expose ToString (and you dont use the .DisplayMamber), then the combobox will be filled with the name of the type instead of the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
If yearlevel.SelectedItem = "Nursery" Then
  txtamount.Text = "1000"
ElseIf yearlevel.SelectedItem = "Kinder" Then
  txtamount.Text = "2000"
End If
```

If this doesn't meet your requirement then please explain your problem
in brief.

Comment: i already tried that and it didn't work. i also tried using the .SelectedText and nothing happened. i have several items in my combobox and what i want to do is that when the user chooses in the combobox, the equivalent amount of it will appear automatically in the textbox